# in one component have an array. and want the other component to have access to this array. they aren't parent-child. i am using routing

Tags: angular, typescript, service, components, message-passing

i want to pass addedToCart array from this component

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  ***
  addedToCart: Item[] = [];
  constructor(private data: DataService) { }


  addToCart(product:Item){
  ***
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.getData()
    .subscribe(
      response =>{
        this.products = response
      }
    )
  }

}
```

i want this component to get that data. is there any easy way?

```
    export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
      cartItems:Item[] | undefined;
      constructor() { }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
      }
    
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use behavior subjects to do the work for you in this case.

Create a common Service file to be used across the application.

In the common service file, you can do this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonService {


initialValuesForProductsArray: string[] = [];

productsArraySource: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject<string[]>(this.initialValuesForProductsArray);

productsArrayObservable: Observable<string[]> = this.productsArraySource.asObservable();

constructor() {}

setProductsArray(data: string[]) {
  this.productsArraySource.next(data);
}

getProductsArray(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.productsArrayObservable;
}

}
```

Now in your component, do this:

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  ***
  addedToCart: Item[] = [];
  constructor(
     private data: DataService,
     private commonService: CommonService <<<<<<<<<<< ADD THIS LINE >>>>>>>>
  ) { }


  addToCart(product:Item){
  ***
}
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.data.getData()
    .subscribe(
      response =>{
        this.products = response;
        this.commonService.setProductsArray(this.products); <<<<<<< ADD THIS LINE >>>>>>

      }
    )
  }

}
```

In your component where you want to get this data, do this:

```
    export class CartComponent implements OnInit {
      cartItems:Item[] | undefined;
      constructor(private commonService: CommonService) {} <<<<< ADD THIS LINE >>>>
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        <<<<<<<< ADD BELOW LINES >>>>>>>>
        this.commonService.getProductsArray().subscribe(data => {
           if (data && data.length) {
              this.cartItems = data;
           }
        });
      }
    
    }
```

thats how you use, behavior subjects to set, get data between components.